# What is the difference between GraalVM native-image tagged with and without 'muslib' prefix?

Tags: graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I do not understand what does this prefix `muslib` means for `GraalVM` native-images. 
Links to native-image [with](https://github.com/graalvm/container/pkgs/container/native-image/57798931?tag=muslib-ol9-java17-22.3.0-b2) and [without](https://github.com/graalvm/container/pkgs/container/native-image/57439792?tag=ol9-java17-22.3.0-b2) the prefix. [Docs](https://github.com/graalvm/container/pkgs/container/native-image#versioning-and-update-policy) does not describe it.

Can anybody explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At [here](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/StaticImages/) says

> Static native images are statically linked binaries which can be used without any additional library dependencies. This makes them easier to distribute and to deploy on slim or distroless container images. They are created by statically linking against musl-libc, a lightweight, fast and simple libc implementation.

That [musl-libc](https://musl.libc.org/) used in those dockers and named as muslib. you can find example docker file [here](https://github.com/graalvm/container/blob/340d5bad16eb0980b4545f491f8fcaeda83d5f4f/rpm-compact/native-image/Dockerfile.ol7-java11-muslib)

And "ol" stands for Oracle Linux check [here](https://github.com/graalvm/container/tree/master/community).